# Default value for getStringExtra() if empty

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Like getIntent().getIntExtra, does getStringExtra have a default value which can be used if the string passed is empty?

I have a method to do this, but was wondering if there was an existing for achieving it to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html, no.

The reason [getIntExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getIntExtra(java.lang.String,%20int)) has a default value parameter, it is because the type returned is a primitive and therefore can't return null.

Answer (score 6):

We cannot check if it is empty, but we can check it by comparing it with null.

```
str = intent.getStringExtra("key");

if(str == null){
  str = "DEFAULT STRING";//Assign default string
}
```